# Can I intercept middle click and new tab link clicks?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Lets say I want to intercept certain anchor element links and track them.  I have the following which works.

HTML

```
<a href="/foo" data-mytracking="fooclicked">go to foo</a>
```

JS

```
$('a[data-mytracking]').click((event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Do some synchronous code to log tracking
  console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-mytracking'), event.target.href);
  window.location = event.target.href;
});
```

Is there a way to have this click code still intercept middle clicks or right click "open in a new tab"?  I know I can do this if I make the `href="javascript:void(0)"`.  But then people lose the ability to open in a new tab.

Comment: Well you could look up the key codes for rmb and mmb and add a listener for these keys. Then you would call the preventDefault() and still get your data-mytracking value.

Answer (score 3):

Some browsers have `auxclick` [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/auxclick). You also can track `event.which` [to track middle button](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/).

```
$("a[data-mytracking]").on('click', function(ev) { 
   if( ev.which== 2 ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // do smth else 
   }
});
```

Opening through a contextmenu is possibly not trackable, but you can have `oncontextmenu` event.

P.S. at least Chrome doesn't trigger click on opening a new tab with a middle button. But it does trigger `mouseup`.

Comment: you can block the entire oncontextmenu event, in the same way that you're preventing middle click. Also plain js alternative `document.querySelector('.css-selector').addEventListener('click', ev=>{//do similar stuff with ev here})`. Specifically blocking just an action from the context menu is not possible in Chrome, at least. I'm unaware of other browsers.

Comment: Plain js has different `which` for different browsers. `jquery` make it common

Comment: Just making it available, not saying which is better. And `.which` is consistent across Firefox and Chrome at least.

Comment: Just ran your code and the event is not being handled at all.  See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLvMxm?editors=1111 and notice that middle clicking link does not log the middle clic.  left clicking works.  (tried in latest chrome on OS X)

Comment: Right. Use `mouseup` instead of `click`. At least Chrome triggers `mouseup` before opening in new tab but doesn't trigger `click`.